# How to get the Application Security ID for a IBM Bluemix android app from the dashboard in the latest version?

Tags: android, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services, bluemix-app-scan

I wanted to build one android app on IBM Bluemix platform and application security key is needed to run this application. I added the app security service also. But I am not able to find the appsecretId in the place mentioned in the tutorials or documents available. This is needed to launch the application. Can anyone tell me where can I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which boilerplate are you using? Mobile Cloud (comes with Push, MAS, and Mobile Data) or the newer MobileFirst Starter (comes with IBM Push Notifications, Mobile Client Access, and Cloudant NoSQLDB)?

For Mobile Cloud you can find the Application Secret in your MAS connection from your Application Overview page (See bottom of pic). Additionally you can click the "Go to Classic Experience" in the top mid-right to go back to the old UI to match with the document you are using.

[image]

For MobileFirst Starter you do not need an application secret and are likely looking at an outdated document intended for Mobile Cloud. All of our MobileFirst Starter samples are hosted on https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services or can be found in the Bluemix document pages.

Comment: I need to use moblie cloud but I am not finding it in the latest Bluemix boilplaters

Comment: Mobile Cloud is in process of deprecation so no new instances can be created. Here's the blogpost going over the deprecation. We strongly recommend trying out the new MobileFirst Starter which contains all the same features and platform availabilities. https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/12/15/important-mobile-services-announcement/

Answer (score 0):

If you are refering to Application Secret key, the new service Mobile Client Access require only appId and Route. (no app secret)

You can find more information here: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobileaccess/getting-started.html In the "next-step section" you can find some example that explains how to use the service ( how you can see the application secret is not required).